# Populate Custom Field Dropdown on Theme Install?

Tags: custom-field, functions

Is there a way to populate the custom field dropdown box when you install a theme? I want to make it easier for users and avoid having them add the terms manually when they first set it up.

Answer (score 1):

the better way would be to create your own meta box nd to add one to your new/edit page screen you can use [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function (look at the example at the bottom for the examples), you can also use [**this class**](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html) which is nicely documented and does most of the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) plugin to create a nice interface for your users.